# Result Set Get all row values in a single column

Tags: java, resultset

I am writing a test at the moment where I need to compare some database results against a UI table using Selenium in Java. I have my UI results arriving in an ArrayList format. My console tells me that the results look like "[27002, 55691, 58716, 95362]". This is working fine.

I have another class which does a JDBC call into my database to obtain the expected results. I'm using the ResultSet method to grab these values. My code looks like the following:
(Note: my JDBC connections etc are handled in the method "runQuery" which I pass my SQL query into)

```
public ArrayList queryForTPOSMembersByHospital() throws SQLException {

    String strQueryText = "select distinct _Member_Number and rest of query here that returns one column of results and 4 rows of data";

    ResultSet rs = runQuery(strQueryText);

    ArrayList<String> memberNos = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs.next()) {

        memberNos.add(rs.getString("_Member_Number"));

        return memberNos;
    }

    return null;

    }
```

But when I output the memberNos I only get a single value [27002] rather than 4 I am expecting.

I'm thinking I need to do something like memberNos.addAll perhaps? rather than memberNos.add? Tried a few things around this method but not getting any luck yet.

Comment: Remove return memberNos; in while do and replace return null; by return memberNos;

Comment: "my JDBC connections etc are handled in the method "runQuery" which I pass my SQL query into" this can be bad. How do you close your connections ?

Comment: @prime I don't actually run a close script. Is this important as things have been working fine so far? If i need to do this then I could add the code to each of the different query methods which call the connection method perhaps?

Comment: @Matt that depends on what you are doing and the requirements. You shouldn't keep your connections open coz that will lead to unnecessary resource leaks and hard to debug problems. I would open a connection when i need to do a query and close it soon after I finished with the result. But that may differ for various reasons. You can adjust your DAOs and use a try with resources methodology when you open the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are returning inside while loop, your code should be

```
while (rs.next()) {

    memberNos.add(rs.getString("_Member_Number"));
}
return memberNos
```

Comment: Of course. How silly of me! And I spent 2 hours trying to fix this. Thanks for your replay and also everyone else who corrected this.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should return data with type `ArrayList` to do so remove return statement from from your code and return `memberNos` like following:

```
public ArrayList queryForTPOSMembersByHospital() throws SQLException {
    String strQueryText = "select distinct _Member_Number and rest of query here that returns one column of results and 4 rows of data";
    ResultSet rs = runQuery(strQueryText);
    ArrayList<String> memberNos = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        memberNos.add(rs.getString("_Member_Number"));
    }
    return memberNos;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
  public ArrayList queryForTPOSMembersByHospital() throws SQLException {
    String strQueryText = "select distinct _Member_Number and rest of query here that returns one column of results and 4 rows of data";
    ResultSet rs = runQuery(strQueryText);
    ArrayList < String > memberNos = new ArrayList < String > ();
    while (rs.next()) {
     memberNos.add(rs.getString("_Member_Number"));
    }
   return memberNos;
 }
```

You were returning from while loop that's why you were getting just one value .